Count of repeating character patterns in a string using MySQL
Given a row in an example table as:



Column A




abcccaaaaddeeaabbaa



How can we get the following output using MYSQL?



sequence
occurrences




aaaa
1


ccc
1


dd
1


ee
1


aa
2


bb
1


a
1


b
1



Tried to compute this using MySQL. Cannot get the right logic for the same.
Edit: My latest attempt with BigQuery:
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 'abcccaaaaddeeaabbaa' AS str
),

Exploded AS (
  SELECT 
    SUBSTR(str, pos, 1) AS char,
    pos,
    LAG(SUBSTR(str, pos, 1)) OVER (ORDER BY pos) AS prev_char
  FROM Input, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, LENGTH(str))) AS pos
),

Grouped AS (
  SELECT
    char,
    pos,
    IF(char = prev_char, 0, 1) AS new_group
  FROM Exploded
),

Sequenced AS (
  SELECT
    char,
    pos,
    SUM(new_group) OVER (ORDER BY pos) AS sequence_id
  FROM Grouped
),

Aggregated AS (
  SELECT
    sequence_id,
    STRING_AGG(char, '' ORDER BY pos) AS sequence
  FROM Sequenced
  GROUP BY sequence_id
),

FinalCounts AS (
  SELECT
    sequence,
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences
  FROM Aggregated
  GROUP BY sequence
)
select * from FinalCounts


A database is not really the right tool to be doing this.  Why are you attempting this in MySQL?

@TimBiegeleisen: This looks to be one of the questions recently encountered in an interview. Wanted to try my hands on the same again.

Stored procedure, loop through the string by each character, check if it is the same as the perevious. If it is not, then insert the pattern in a temp table. At the end do a select on the temp table with count and group by. But my answer would be not to do it in mysql in the first place.

Surely "Column A" is not really the column name?  Show the actual table and column names you are using

Don't delete this post @sqlmnk because of negative voting. Because the answer by ysth is awesome...

bigquery is not mysql.  please don't tag bigquery questions mysql or use bigquery to test sql for mysql

@ysth: This is not a bigquery question but one for MySQL. Just wanted to post a method which I found was close to solvable for me. The answer is intended to be in MySQL.

Split it up into one row per character, then identify runs of characters and summarize them:
with recursive chars as (
  select bar,
    char_length(bar) idx,
    substr(bar, -1) ch
  from foo

  union all

  select bar, idx-1, substr(bar,idx-1,1)
  from chars
  where idx > 1
),
charruns as (
  select ch, idx,
    count(1) over (order by idx)
      - count(1) over (partition by ch order by idx)
      run_id
  from chars
),
runs as (
  select
    repeat(ch, count(1)) sequence,
    min(idx) idx
  from charruns
  group by ch, run_id
),
occurrences as (
  select
    sequence,
    count(1) occurrences,
    min(idx) idx
  from runs
  group by sequence
)
select sequence, occurrences
from occurrences
order by char_length(sequence) desc, idx

fiddle

My Hat's off to you! @ysth.
I checked your answer, it's really awesome how you think and resolve through sql query.

here is a shorter query
SET @in = 'abcccaaaaddeeaabbaa';

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(@in, '^(.)\\1*') AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) AS prefix,
           CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(@in, '^(.)\\1*', '') AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) AS modified_string,
           1 AS step
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(modified_string, '^(.)\\1*') AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) AS prefix,
           CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(modified_string, '^(.)\\1*', '') AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) AS modified_string,
           step + 1 AS step
    FROM cte
    WHERE modified_string != '' AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(modified_string, '^(.)\\1*') IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT prefix as sequence,
       SUM(1) as occurrences
FROM cte
GROUP BY prefix
ORDER BY LENGTH(prefix) DESC, prefix;

result:
sequence    occurrences
aaaa    1
ccc     1
aa      2
bb      1
dd      1
ee      1
a       1
b       1   

sample dbfiddle
sample with a table dbfiddle
